# Understanding React Redux Reducer and MapstateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm having trouble understanding how the redux state assigns the state objects based on the action payload and the reducer functions.  Below is my sample code.  I've made notes and asked questions along the different sections, but in summary these are my questions:

- Why does Option 2 below not work?
- Why do I have to map my state to my competitionList prop using `state.competitions` and not `state.items`?
- Any resources to get a good grasp of how react and redux connect and mapping functions work.  I've already gone through the official docs and done some googling, but perhaps someone has a reference that they found easier to understand all the different options and ways of mapping state and dispatch.

My Action code:

```
function getAll() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request());

        myService.getAll()
            .then(
                competitions => dispatch(success(competitions)),
                error => dispatch(failure(error))
            );
    };

    function request() { return { type: constants.GETALL_REQUEST } }
    function success(competitions) { return {type: constants.GETALL_SUCCESS, competitions}}
    function failure(error) { return {type: constants.GETALL_FAILURE, error}} 
}
```

My reducer code:

```
import { constants } from '../_constants';

const initialState = {items: [], loading: false, selected: null}

export function competitions(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.GETALL_REQUEST:
      return {
        loading: true
      };
    case constants.GETALL_SUCCESS:
          console.log("the action value: ", action)
      return {
        items: action.competitions
      };
    case constants.GETALL_FAILURE:
          console.log("the failed action value: ", action)
      return { 
        error: action.error
      };
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

In my component I have a mapStateToProp function which I pass to connect.  The first one does not work.  Why?

Option 1 - Not working

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { selected, ...competitions } = state.competitions;

    return {
        competitionList: competitions,
        isLoading: state.loading
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

This one works, but I would like the competitionList variable to have the returned items array instead of the whole state object, so I tried to do something like this `competition: state.competitions.items` but it raises an error.

Option 2 - Partially working (I want to only assign the competition items)

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    competitionList: state.competitions,
    isLoading: state.loading
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

I cannot do:

```
const { competitionList } = this.props;

{competitionList.map(competition =>
     <tr key={competition.competitionId}>
        <td>{competition.competitionName}</td>
     </tr>
 )}
```

I have to do:

```
const { competitionList } = this.props;

{competitionList.items.map(competition =>
     <tr key={competition.competitionId}>
        <td>{competition.competitionName}</td>
     </tr>
 )}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the point that you are missing is when you combine your reducers, each one will have a key because they are objects.

In the file you combine your reducers, you probably have something like that:

```html
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import todos from './todos'
import competitions from './competitions'

export default combineReducers({
  todos,
  competitions
})
```

After that, your state will look like this:

```html
{
  todos:{},
  competitions:{
    items: [],
    loading: false,
    selected: null
  }

}
```

Explained that I think everything will be easier.

**Option 1 - Not working**: It is not working because you don't have`competitions` attribute inside the `competitions` state. Even if you have, you should not use the `...` before it. If you replace the `competitions` for `items`, it is going to work, because `items` are inside the `competitions` state:

```html
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { selected, items } = state.competitions;

    return {
        competitionList: items,
        isLoading: state.loading
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

Or we can improve it, to make it shorter:

```html
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { selected, items } = state.competitions;

    return {
        items,
        selected
        isLoading: state.loading
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

Doing this way, you can use this part of your code:

```html
const { items } = this.props;

{items.map(competition =>
   <tr key={competition.competitionId}>
      <td>{competition.competitionName}</td>
   </tr>
 )}
```

There is another point I would like to point, Probably your `isLoading` variable is not working either, because you are trying to read it directly from the state, instead of from a reducer in the state.

**Edited:** I missed another point. Your reducer always has to return the whole state instead of just an attribute of it.

```html
import { constants } from '../_constants';

const initialState = {items: [], loading: false, selected: null, error: null}

export function competitions(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
case constants.GETALL_REQUEST:
  /*return {
    loading: true
  };*/
  //returning that I will overwrite your competition state with this object.
  

  // this will keep all the competition state and will gerenate a new object changing only the loading attribute
  return {
    ...state,
    loading:true
}
case constants.GETALL_SUCCESS:
      console.log("the action value: ", action)
  return {
    ...state,
    items: action.competitions
  };
case constants.GETALL_FAILURE:
      console.log("the failed action value: ", action)
  return { 
    ...state,
    error: action.error
  };
default:
  return state
  }
}
```